# Angular 2 Bootstrapping Options - AOT vs JIT

Tags: angular, jit, angular2-aot, angular2-bootstrapping

Just kick started with Angular 2.

1. What are the various Bootstrapping options in angular 2?
2. Why is that when I make a change and refresh the index.html takes little time to retrieve the HTML markups?
3. Differences between them

Comment: FWIW there's also the Angular Universal which I didn't see in the other answers - so basically bootstrap the initial page/module/whatever server-side, then re-hydrate once the app is loaded on the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two options

1. Dynamic bootstrapping

   - compiler used **JIT** (Just in Time).
   - dynamically compiles the ts files in the browser.
   - this is the reason the index.html takes little time to retrieve the markups.
   - main.ts contains the following

     ```
     import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
     import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

     platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
     ```

     2. Static bootstrapping
   - compiler used **AoT** (Ahead of Time).
   - The ts files are compiled into js files and then rendered to the browser.
   - By this, a set of js files containing modules and factories are created there by making them light weight.
   - Mostly used in the case of mobiles and legacy networks.
   - main.ts contains the following

     ```
     import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
     import { AppModuleNgFactory }              from '../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';

     platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
     ```

Differences 
[image]

Comment: You could mention that all these benefits in AoT are paid for bit longer compilation time. AoT is also supported by angular-cli witch makes it unnoticeable during development

Answer (score 3):

In Angular there are two ways of compilation

- JIT - Just-in-Time Compilation AOT
- Ahead-of-Time Compilation

I would like to add four major differences when it comes to JIT vs AOT compilation

```
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
|                    JIT                 |                   AOT                       |
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
| JIT compilation as the name implies,   | AOT compilation compiles the application at |
| compiles  the application Just in Time | build time                                  |
| in the browser at runtime              |                                     |
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
|For JIT compilation the browser needs to| AOT compilation it does not have to         |
|download the angular compiler           |                                             |
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
|While the application is being JIT      | With AOT, the application is precompiled    | 
|compiled in the browser, users have     | so there no such wait                       |
|to wait                                 |                                             |
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
|With JIT compilation, the template      | With AOT compilation we will come to        |
|binding errors are only know at runtime | now about them at build time.               |
|----------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|
```

By default, the following2 commands use JIT compilation

```
ng build
ng serve
```

With either of these command we can use **`- -aot`** option to turn on AOT

```
ng build --aot
ngserve --aot
```

To turn off ACT for the production build, set **`- - aot`** option to **`false`**

```
 ng build -- prod --aot false
```

Comment: what's the point of this answer? The question is about bootstrapping using platformBrowser/platformBrowserDynamic