# Angular 2 AOT vs JIT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jit, angular2-aot

I was just reading [Angular 2 AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) documentation and a few questions poped up

1. The documentation clearly favours AOT over JIT and mentioned all the good stuff about how AOT is better. If that is the case  why wouldn't AOT be the default build rather than doing `ng build --prod --aot`
2. The documentation goes through in detail about how to set it up. Would `ng build --prod --aot` be good enough to ignore all those setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Bootstrapping Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050331/angular-2-bootstrapping-options)

Comment: Concerning your first question, note that Angular 5 [will default](https://youtu.be/anzsE2TbCyk?t=39m20s) to the AOT compiler for simplicity reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. The documentation clearly favours AOT over JIT and mentioned all the good stuff about how AOT is better. If that is the case  why wouldn't AOT be the default build rather than doing `ng build --prod --aot`

AoT is the default for `-prod` as of beta 28.

It's still NOT the default for dev build. Why? Because it takes longer time to compile and in dev you want fast feedback.

Note that the current version of the Angular CLI at the time of writing is beta.29, and the package name has changed from `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli`.

> 2. The documentation goes through in detail about how to set it up. Would `ng build --prod --aot` be good enough to ignore all those setup?

Yes!

And you can just `ng build -prod` if you are using the latest version of the CLI.

Comment: FYI: Your link is dead.  Looks like they took out the webpack-config.ts file.

Comment: Yeah. They had several re-structures since that beta. Last (at the time of writing) with the addition of Angular devkit and moving stuff there. I'll just remove the link. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 3):

As part of angular-cli, you should have the required NPM dependencies to compile using AOT.  It seems as though AOT will be enabled if targeting prod in [the very near future](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4138).  It was [accidentally enabled by default](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3354) in an earlier version of angular-cli and that caused a few headaches.

Running `ng build --prod --aot=true` will work on a brand new angular-cli application without additional configuration or setup.