# What flag can I add to Angular `ng serve` to make hotload show strict build errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I wanted to add a question within the comment section of this post: [Angular 2 AOT vs JIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979418/angular-2-aot-vs-jit?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't have enough rep points yet.

I have an Angular app that shows errors when I build but not in dev. I understand the desire to get quick feedback in dev but for this application it is causing issues in the gratification of quick deployment after working in the dev enviroment for extended time. Instead of doing `ng serve` to get the feedback and then do `ng build` right after to make sure at a later time I will be able to deploy; is there a flag I can add to `ng serve` that will do this for me?

At the moment I use `ng serve --aot` but that is not strict enough to show errors that will fail at build. Right now the application I have is not that big, so I will find it acceptable if my `ng serve` loads slower.

Here's a snippet of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXXX",
  "url": "XXXXXXX",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation of all the build options of ng serve

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

For your case, try

```
ng serve --e=prod
```

or

```
ng serve --aot --e=prod
```

Hope this works.

Also try --source-maps=false. This looks like speeding up things.

Comment: Thank you! The first one wasn't strict enough, but the second solution worked perfectly!

Comment: adding `--source-map=false` can greatly speed things up. Obviously the `prod` and `aot` slow things down - and if you're looking to just fix all those silly small things this should speed up the process.